# Visual Basic 2016 Dataset with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with my Data base linked to Visual Basic 2016. The connection between the project and the MySQL data base is good, but as soon as I try to create a **tableadapter** (for a select re-query for instance) I have the following message:

[image: Tableadapter error]

Translation:

> Generated SELECT instruction
>
> [A]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection can't be converted to [B]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection. The type A comes from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' in the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\MySqul.Data.dll'. The type B comes from 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' in the file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_6.9.9.0_c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll'.

Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried to use?

Comment: I did code anything this a message I get in the assistant when I try to create a new tableadapter.

Comment: It looks like you have a different version of the .dll in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\MySqul.Data.dll" directory as opposed to the version in the GAC (MySql.Data.dll).  I also notice they are named differently (MySqul.Data.dll vs MySql.Data.dll).  Maybe try taking the version from the GAC and referencing that instead of the one in the "PrivateAssemblies" directory?

Comment: You might be right, I'll try that. But I don't understand where the error comes from, the installer did everything on its own.